# TransferSpreadsheet method cuts string

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, import, import-from-excel

I have created an Access form to allow analysts to import data from excel sheets into SQL Server.

Once they press a button on the form it is TransferSpreadsheet method which is fired for data import.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet Import, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Upload_tmp", TempVars!strFN, True, ""
```

Where `TempVars!strFN` - is path to excel file.

Everything works perfect except one tiny thing: there is one text column "Comments" which can contain string more than 255 characters length. All those comments are beeing truncated till 255 characters.

"Comments" column in access database has MEMO datatype.

After hours of testing I found out that if a string with long comment(more than 255 characters) is in the beginning of file - everything will be fine - it won't be truncated. But if it is not - that is it - string is truncated.

Do anybody knows the trick to make this work always? Users said they are not going to order files each time before importing them. Maybe there is another method in Access to import excel data?

thanks